# How to save query without format in Jquery-maskMoney

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I've some problem to save format from Jquery-maskMoney,
i already success implemented Jquery-maskMoney in my web form, here my code :

**Javascrypt:**

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#currency").maskMoney({ formatOnBlur: true, reverse: true, prefix: 'Rp ', selectAllOnFocus: true, precision: 0 });
  })
</script>
```

**Views:**

```
        <label class="control-label" for="nama_hukuman">Nilai Proyek</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" class="span" name="nilai" value="<?php echo $nilai; ?>" style="width:300px;" placeholder="Harga Pengadaan.." id="currency">
        </div>
```

my problem, after i saved the data, data will save with Jquery-maskMoney format (with Currency and comas).

How to save the data without the format?

ex.

Website Form            ->  Saved in Database SQL

Rp 1,000,000            ->  1000000

*Thanks for your help*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER UPDATE**

For some strange reason the **.maskMoney('unmasked')** doesn't work. Hence a workaround can be based on the **input** event. In the following snippet I changed the hidden field to a text field for test purposes:

```js
$("#currency").maskMoney({
    formatOnBlur: true,
    reverse: true,
    prefix: 'Rp ',
    selectAllOnFocus: true,
    precision: 0,
    decimal: '.',
    thousands: ','
}).on('input', function(e) {
    $('#' + this.id + 'Hidden').val(this.value.replace(/Rp\s|[.,]/g, ''));
}).trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney/master/dist/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>


<form>
    <label class="control-label" for="nama_hukuman">Nilai Proyek</label>

    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="currencyHidden">
        <input type="text" class="span" name="nilai" value="Rp 1,000,000" style="width:300px;"
               placeholder="Harga Pengadaan.." id="currency">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**OLD ANSWER**

You need to use:

> [.maskMoney('unmasked')](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney): return a float value (ex.: 'R$ 1.234,56' => 1234.56). PS: If you have only one input field, you should use this way .maskMoney('unmasked')[0], since it will always return an array.
>
> [.maskMoney('destroy')](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney): removes maskMoney from an element

I can suggest two strategies:

**First strategy**

On form submit you can get the **unmasked** value and set the field with this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    var v = $("#currency").maskMoney('destroy').val().replace(/Rp\s|[.,]/g, '');
    $("#currency").val(v);
})
```

```js
$("#currency").maskMoney({
    formatOnBlur: true,
    reverse: true,
    prefix: 'Rp ',
    selectAllOnFocus: true,
    precision: 0
});
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    var v = $("#currency").maskMoney('destroy').val()
            .replace(/Rp\s|[.,]/g, '');
    $("#currency").val(v);
    //
    // The following line is only for test....
    //
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney/master/dist/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>


<form>
    <label class="control-label" for="nama_hukuman">Nilai Proyek</label>

    <div class="controls">
        <input type="hidden" id="currencyHidden">
        <input type="text" class="span" name="nilai" value="Rp 1,000,000" style="width:300px;"
               placeholder="Harga Pengadaan.." id="currency">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**The second strategy**

You can use an input hidden  field and so for each **input** event you may fill this hidden field with the **unmasked** value:

```
.on('input', function(e) {
      var v = $(this).maskMoney('unmasked')[0];
      $('#' + this.id + 'Hidden').val(v);
 });
```

```js
$("#currency").maskMoney({
  formatOnBlur: true,
  reverse: true,
  prefix: 'Rp ',
  selectAllOnFocus: true,
  precision: 0
}).on('input', function(e) {
  var v = $(this).maskMoney('unmasked')[0];
  $('#' + this.id + 'Hidden').val(v);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney/master/dist/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>


<form>
    <label class="control-label" for="nama_hukuman">Nilai Proyek</label>

    <div class="controls">
        <input type="hidden" id="currencyHidden">
        <input type="text" class="span" name="nilai" value="Rp 1,000,000" style="width:300px;"
               placeholder="Harga Pengadaan.." id="currency">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks before for your suggestion, it still saved with the currency in sql, your first suggestion saved with this format `1232.1311` and your second suggestion saved like the format before `Rp 23,123`

Comment: @karisma You are right. Answer updated. I added a new solution. Let me know. Thanks

Comment: i can't save the data, submit button look like locked, (:

Comment: @karisma I added **e.preventDefault();** in order to let you see what happens. Please, remove that line in your code.

Comment: may you give solution for my next problem in this question?? [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47057287/maskmoney-error-in-dynamic-form